# Issue to insert record with datetime to SQL Server 2014 via ODBC C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2014

I have a simple c++ code to insert a record in SQL Server 2014 via ODBC. It works fine with varchar fields, but it does not work with datetime field.

```
SQLCHAR buf[64];
SQLLEN len;
SQLCHAR buf2[255];
SQLLEN len2;
SQLLEN len3;
double f;
rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 19, 0, (SQLCHAR*)buf, 0, &len);
rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 255, 0, (SQLCHAR*)buf2, 0, &len2);
rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_FLOAT, SQL_FLOAT, 15, 0, &f, 0, &len3);
rc = SQLPrepare(hstmt, (SQLCHAR*)"insert into test(timepoint,strvalue,floatvalue) values (?,?,?)", SQL_NTS);

strcpy((char*)buf,"20171010 00:08:14");
len=strlen("20171017 00:08:14");
strcpy((char*)buf2,"simple string");
len2=strlen("simple string");
f=1.34e+8;

SQLSMALLINT NumParams;
SQLNumParams(hstmt, &NumParams);
rc = SQLExecute(hstmt);
```

Can anybody help to understand that is wrong?
I've got always:

"22018:1:0:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid character value for cast specification\n"

If I'm wrong here with my question, please give a hint which forum fits better. I've spent some days, but can't find the solution. For any help would be very appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can cast various strings in different date formats to a *real date* implicitly, but you must be very careful how to use them:

There is the **unseparated** date format "yyyyMMdd", which **cannot carry a time!**

```
SELECT CAST('20170102' AS DATETIME) --2017-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

The most universal format is `ISO8601`, which is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` (beware of the the `T` in the middle and the usage of 24 hours format!)

```
SELECT CAST('2017-01-02T12:23:59' AS DATETIME) --2017-01-02 12:23:59.000
```

And - last but not least - there are three `ODBC` formats:

```
SELECT CAST({d'2017-01-02'} AS DATETIME)           --2017-01-02 00:00:00.000
SELECT CAST({t'23:35:51'} AS DATETIME)             --2018-01-19 23:35:51.000 (today!)
SELECT CAST({ts'2017-01-02 23:35:51'} AS DATETIME) --2017-01-02 23:35:51.000
```

And a last - important! - hint: Some formats work, but depend on the system's settings. This can work for you and pass all internal tests, but might break on a customer's machine:

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST('2017-01-02 23:35:51' AS DATETIME) -- Jan 2
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST('2017-01-02 23:35:51' AS DATETIME) -- Feb 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried already the ISO8601 format, with value 2017-10-10T00:08:14, but I've got the same issue

Comment: @Rick, What is the datatype of your table's column? Try to use a `VARCHAR(100)` instead and see what's inserted. Did you try this without the `T` (`ODBC`-format `ts`)? You can use the *Profiler* to monitor all commands. Thus you can see what is passed over to SQL Server. Try a *naked date* (`20170102`) and a *naked time* (`23:33:43`)

Comment: the column is of type datetime

Comment: sometimes it works if I use instead of string the SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT and     rc = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, sizeof(dt), 0, &dt, 0, &len);
, but now it does not work anymore, it returns code 99

Comment: @Rick you can try to pass the ISO format AS Unicode (ucs-2) string. This should be casted implicitly

Comment: I found only one solution till now that work, in the bind set instead of SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP --> SQL_CHAR, everything else doesn't work. then it doesn't matter that format I use, everything works. I don't understand the reason, the type of column is datetime, not varchar

Comment: @Rick I'm not familiar with your technology, but it might be a reason that [`TIMESTAMP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) is **not the same** as `DATETIME`. Passing the value as string will work, but be careful with system's settings, especially the date format's order (`dm` or `md`). You say: *everything works*, but this might fail on a different machine...